# How long does a control-M job stays in waiting state for the pre-requisites to be met by default?

Tags: control-m

If keep active is given as 0, how long the job waits for the pre-requisites to be met?

If keep active is given as 1, how long the job waits for the pre-requisites to be met?

My requirement is job should come into plan on certain time on first day and if pre-requisites aren't met that should go away from plan by the same time following(next) day.

Answer (score 0):

Control-M works around the fundamental concept of New Day Processing (NDP). NDP sets up your scheduled jobs for the upcoming day and does housekeeping on the jobs that were there during the previous "day". The timing of your NDP is set by the CM Admin. Say, for example, your, your NDP is at 8 am and you have a new job that waits until 1 pm, has an input condition and keep active = 0. Should the input condition not show up then your job will be cleared out (unexecuted) at 8 am the next day.

If you have keep active set as 1 (or more) the job will survive NDP and potentially run (upon receiving the input cond) the next day. However it will wait on the from time (1 pm in our example) unless you use the "allow submission past next New Day" option. You can also set a "to" time, which sets the latest possible time for when the job could submit - unfortunately that would also limit you on the "first" day. To cleanup on the second day (in the way you describe) I think you'd have to create another job to manipulate the original (via ctmpsm ot the api).